# How to access protected data members of base class of its derived class by passing objects to another derive class

Tags: c++

I have already looked up some answers to this problem and got it working, but I can't seem understand how this one answer works, can someone enlighten me what is going on in the line `void show(input& obj){cout <<obj.*&output::x <<' ' <<obj.*&output::y <<endl;}`.
Here is the full code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class baseClass{
protected:
    int x, y;
public:
    virtual void func()=0;
};
class input:public baseClass{
public:
    void func(){
        cout <<"Enter value x and y respectively: ";
        cin >>x >>y;
        cout <<endl;
    }
};
class output:public baseClass{
public:
    void func(){}
    void show(input& obj){
        cout <<obj.*&output::x <<' ' <<obj.*&output::y <<endl;    /*Is this a reliable and effective
    }                                                              way of calling the protected data members?*/
};
int main(){
baseClass* ptr;
input callIn;
output callOut;
ptr=&callIn;
ptr->func();
callOut.show(callIn);
}
```

I'm trying to access the protected data member of input class which is inherited from the parent baseClass by passing it object to another child class.

Comment: Why is `output` not outputting its own `x` and `y`? It feels like there's something wrong with the design if you have to do stuff like that.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I feel the question is more about the technicalities of access rather than a study on the design.

Comment: @SergeyA  Yeah, it could be that - or an XY problem.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I could have done that along time ago, but I have wondered about accessing the protected members of of a derived class (which is inherited from the base) and access it through to another derived class, because i have been always encountering this problem. I thought i could access it.

Comment: "_i have been always encountering this problem_" - Ok, I don't remember having encountered it at all.

Comment: @TedLyngmo since im just new to C++ i have been trying to program and applying the lesson i learned (specially in OOP), thus i have wondered that what if the data members of an object (inherited from the base class) of this derive class can be manipulated to another derive class (same parent).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is legal, albeit convoluted and non-intuitive.

The gist of the magic happens here:

```
cout <<obj.*&output::x <<' ' <<obj.*&output::y <<endl;
```

Here, `&output::x` denotes a pointer-to-member, namely `x` in the `output` class. This operation is permitted, since `output` has `baseClass` as it's parent and thus has access to it's protected members.

Now you can access a member in class `input` using the pointer-to-member, as access controls do not control access through pointer-to-member (they can not!). They rely on control invoked during taking the address of the said member.

To make the code a bit more clear, one can use local variable to store pointer:

```
   int baseClass::* p = &output::y;
   cout << obj.*p << endl;
```

Also, while I find the technique worth understanding, I am not discussing whether it is appropriate to use. Often if you have to resort to magic tricks like this you might want to instead revisit your design and class hierarchy, but I would not rule out a potential use case for this.

Comment: I kind a get what you are saying in the first part. I lost in the part you are talking about access control do not control access part.

Comment: @Phantomatrixx Access control is what blocks you from getting to private members or protected members from non-children. Normally `output` can't access non-public members in `input`, as they are not directly related. However, this check only happens if you try to access member directly (like obj.x). If you are going through the pointer, compiler can't stop you, as it generally doesn't know which member you are accessing (pointer can point to anywhere).

Comment: Does this compromise the protected data in the baseClass in any shape or form?

Comment: @Phantomatrixx define 'compromise'. Access controls are well-defined and do what they are expected to do.